# Getting IllegalStateException on response.setBufferSize, but only sometimes

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jboss, response, illegalstateexception

I have a web application using Spring 3.2.11.RELEASE, running on JBoss 7.1.3.Final.

The application runs on a single application server.

Mysteriously Sometimes my app I will get intermittent `java.lang.IllegalStateException` on a particular controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/sync", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void sync(@RequestParam final String orgId,
                 final HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException
{
    response.setBufferSize(1024);
```

…

The `response.setBufferSize` method will occasionally produce the below error, despite the fact it is the first line of my method:

```
13:47:40,954 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/clever].[dispatcher]] (http-/127.0.0.1:8081-1)  Servlet.service() for servlet dispatcher threw exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.setBufferSize(ResponseFacade.java:234) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
        at org.collegeboard.springboard.clever.controller.CleverOrganizationController.sync(CleverOrganizationController.java:112) [classes:]
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1017.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_65]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) [rt.jar:1.6.0_65]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) [rt.jar:1.6.0_65]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215) [spring-web-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132) [spring-web-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104) [spring-webmvc-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745) [spring-webmvc-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:685) [spring-webmvc-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80) [spring-webmvc-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:919) [spring-webmvc-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:851) [spring-webmvc-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:953) [spring-webmvc-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:855) [spring-webmvc-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar:1.0.1.Final]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:829) [spring-webmvc-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar:1.0.1.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:165) [jboss-as-web-7.1.3.Final.jar:7.1.3.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:372) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:679) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:931) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680) [rt.jar:1.6.0_65]
```

Any ideas how I can make this go away for good?

Comment: Do you have any custom Filter declared? Do you have any ControllerAdvice? Could you post your fully Controller Class?

Comment: @Dave A Hey try what I have implemented. any problem comment on me

Answer (score 3):

You should call `setBufferSize` earlier, before it is committed. You can check to see if it was already committed, by calling `isCommitted()` on the `ServletResponse` object. The doc for  [isCommitted()](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#isCommitted%28%29), states:

> A committed response has already had its status code and headers written.

This has happened to me also, when calling `setBufferSize` on the `ServletResponse` too late. For you, this could be a threading issue, which would explain why this happens erratically.

The doc for [setBufferSize(int)](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#setBufferSize%28int%29) explains when you get the `IllegalStateException`:

> This method must be called before any response body content is written; if content has been written or the response object has been committed, this method throws an IllegalStateException.'

Comment: I can't run "setBufferSize" any earlier.  It is already the first line of the method so how do I run it earlier?

Comment: I was thinking about setting the buffer size in the block that calls `sync`. This way, it will be configured before the response is written. There is no point in setting a buffer on a response that has already been written.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot comment so adding comment as an answer if it may help you. Just check if you have autoFlush=true in jsp then that could be possible reason. Also you can check using response.isCommitted() in controller method before setting response buffersize.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that spring has already written something in the response. 
For example, if You have declarate a modelAtribute.

Comment: This is the only method in the controller.  There is nothign else in there with a @ModelAttributre annotation or anything similar.  Is there a way to tell what has already been written?

Comment: if response.getOutputStream() return a ByteArrayOutputStream You can also read ((ByteArrayOutputStream)response.getOutputStream()).toByteArray()

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: PWC3999: Cannot create a session
>   after the response has been committed.

I tried everything whatever is mentioned in the above blog. How ever nothing worked out.

I finally came to know that there was form ,  which had an action of `j_security_check` and because of this form the problem was coming up.

```
<h:form method="post" action="j_security_check">
```

To resolve this issue I created one more empty form without any action in the parent xhtml file and it resolved the issue.

I still need to figure out, why the issue got resolved after using the empty form tag in the parent xhtml file.

Hope this will help somebody.